# USA: Do 911/PD phone operators have a 'duty to rescue'?

Tags: united-states, police, common-law, moral-duty

As I understand it: ['duty to rescue'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duty_to_rescue) does not ***generally*** exist for regular citizens in the USA. (Some exceptions apply!)

Let's say I'm in Europe and I call the general inquiry phone number of a local (city) police department in the United States to report a suicidal individual local to them. Do any of the following entities have a 'duty to rescue' in the following situations?:

1. Police officers answering the phone.
2. Non-police officer employees answering phones at a (local?) PD.
3. The dispatch operators that #1 and #2 connect me to.
4. The dispatch operators I get when I dial 911 while being in the USA myself.
5. The legal entities of either the police department or the emergency services dispatch (or other involved party?)

---

Note: I have tried to keep this question as narrow/focused as possible. Let me know if there's any issues with the question. I'm not familiar with law all that much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No

More generally, government agencies have [no duty to protect](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/12/18/us/parkland-shooting-lawsuit-ruling-police.html?smid=tw-nytnational&smtyp=cur).

> In the cases *DeShaney vs. Winnebago* and *Town of Castle Rock vs. Gonzales*, the supreme court has ruled that police agencies are not obligated to provide protection of citizens. In other words, police are well within their rights to [pick and choose](https://mises.org/power-market/police-have-no-duty-protect-you-federal-court-affirms-yet-again) when to intervene to protect the lives and property of others — even when a threat is apparent.

In the [united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) , the situation is the same with the relevant case being [*Hill v Chief Constable of West Yorkshire*](https://www.dacbeachcroft.com/en/gb/articles/2018/february/duty-of-care-owed-by-police-clarified-by-supreme-court-with-a-sting-in-the-tail/), a precedent followed in [australia](/questions/tagged/australia).

However, the police, fire fighters, ambulance officers etc. do owe the same common law duty of care as everyone else where such a duty exists if and when they do choose to act, unless specifically exempted by law. For example, they owe a duty to people in custody or innocent bystanders.